# How can you make a tabs on a specific page in .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, shell, navigation, maui, .net-maui.shell

I want to make tabs for a specific page, but with AppShell I can just do this for everypage. I just want tabs only in one page, and not the others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your Tabpage after the first page, you just have to navigate to the AppShell that contains the Tabpage. For example, in an app that has a LoginPage and next the Tabpage, you can do it like this.

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
App.Current.MainPage = LoginPage;
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```
<ShellContent
    Title="Home"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate vm:HomePage}"
    />
```

And then, just navigate to HomePage (Tabpage) using Shell navigation.

```
App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the MainPage as `NavigationPage` and then navigate to the specific `Tabbedpage`.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

In your MainPage, you can navigate to the specific Tabbedpage` like below:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyTabbedPage());
```